# TemplatedParent binding doesn't work properly

Tags: wpf, binding

This binding works just fine

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tariffs}" Margin="6">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <custControls:RoundButton Name="TariffButton" Margin="3"
          Content="{Binding TariffName}" Style="{DynamicResource TariffButton}">
               <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                  <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="PickUpTariff">
                      <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding Path=Content, 
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type custControls:RoundButton}}}" />
                      </cal:ActionMessage>
                  </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
          </custControls:RoundButton>
       </DataTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

This binding passes content object properly.
When I change binding to this:

```
--all the same and this line is changed to this
<cal:Parameter  Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TariffName}" />
```

It does not work!
So I have a question why it does not work and how to determine which ancestor is actually treated as a templated parent by WPF?

p.s. The following binding works fine

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tariffs}" Margin="6">
```

**Update 1.**
Here is the sample with templated parent binding which works fine.

```
 <ListBox Grid.Row="2" x:Name="StationsListView"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             BorderThickness="0"
             DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModelKey}"
             SelectionMode="Extended"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Stations}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <customControls:VirtualizingWrapPanel x:Name="StationsPanel" IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <customControls:RoundButton MinWidth="380" Margin="3" Padding="16"
                                            Style="{DynamicResource CommonButtonStyle}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}"
                               Style="{DynamicResource Verdana22BoldWhite}"
                               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="StationHasChosen">
                                <cal:Parameter
                                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=FullName}" />
                            </cal:ActionMessage>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </customControls:RoundButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

RoundButton and VirtualizingWrapPanel are both custom controls, but only for RoundButton I have defined ControlTemplate explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

TemplatedParent binding can be used only when we define ControlTemplate for the Parent. You are not doing so. Get more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.templatedparent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Ok, I have very similar example where the templated parent binding works for me and I didn't define ControlTemplate. See the sample in update.